# Analog PCI from Linux Python

Tags: python, pci

I need to send data from my linux system in analog format to another device.

I wonder if anybody has experience with a PCI card that works well with Linux and is possible to control from Python, possibly by using some Python package.

If that is not possible, maybe someone has an alternate suggestion on how to address this.

Comment: are you trying to communicate with a raspberrypi?

Comment: How complex does the data need to be?  IOW, is it something you could rig up a harness to use a sound card for?

Comment: Hi,
It is not a raspberry. It is an analog control device. the data is not very complex. It is just three number which I must represent as analog voltages and send them from my Linux system to another device.

Comment: @AustinHemmelgarn, do you mean that I could use a standard sound card to output my values as an analog signal? That is an interesting possibility.

Comment: Yes, although you would probably need some external hardware (probably custom designed) to properly isolate it and adjust to the voltages you need.  One of my friends who's an electrical engineer actually set things up so he can use his computer's sound card as an oscilloscope and waveform generator, so this type of thing is possible.

Comment: @AustinHemmelgarn It is interesting. But I think it is fine to get a PCI card if I find how to control it through Python.

Comment: Yeah, a dedicated card will obviously work too, I was just tossing out the suggestion because for some people it's easier to put together the hardware to make such a solution work than to get the software written to make it work with a PCI card.